# Prove that the equation $2^x-1=y^2$ has no integer solutions where $x\:>1$

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Here's what I did:

Rearrange  $2^x-1=y^2$ $\rightarrow $ **$2^x-y^2=1$**

All the numbers when $x>1$ are:

$\left(4,\:8,\:16,\:32,\:64,\:128,\:256...\right)$

For $2^x-y^2=1$ to hold true, $y^2$ has to be **one** less than $2^x$ for all $x>1$

Therefore, the only possible solutions for $y^2$ are:

$\left(3,\:7,\:15,\:31,\:63,\:127,\:255\right)$ **(which are prime numbers)**

Since we have $y^2$, there is no $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $y^2$ is a prime number such as $\left(3,\:7,\:15,\:31,\:63,\:127,\:255\right)$

Thus, there are no solutions for the equation $2^x - 1 = y^2$ where $x>1$.

> I don't know how to make this proof more mathematical looking with
> equations and stuff. If anyone can direct me to come up with a more
> 'formal' approach, that would be appreciated!

Comment: 15,63 are not prime.

Comment: There's a very simple proof for this. Hint: Check both sides of the equation modulo $4$. A perfect square can only be $0,1\pmod 4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that every square number is either $0\mod 4$ or $1\mod 4$. It follows that for $x>2$, we have that $2^x-1\equiv 3\mod 4$ and hence, cannot be a square. So if there is a solution it must happen when $x\leq 2$.

We can manually check that the only remaining potential solution of $x=2$ gives no integer solutions for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

$y = 2^x - 1$ has a root for $x = 0$, because its asymptotic at $y = -1$, and is continually increasing. However, $y^2 = 2^x - 1$ tells a different story. It still has a root at $x = 0$, but its parabolic in nature in the horizontal direction.

The reason your function has no roots because of your domain of $x > 1$. $\frac{dy}{dx} > 0$, for $x > 1$ and at $x = 1, y = 1$. Hence, what can you conclude about the nature of the function and its position in a cartesian plane after $x > 1$. Will it every hit the x-axis?

Answer (score 0):

The point of a mathematical proof is not to be *'mathematical looking with equations and stuff'*. The point is to to show that some conclusion follows logically from some premise.

Here the premise is that $x$ and $y$ are integers, with $x>1$, such that $2^x-1=y^2$. The conclusion is that this is impossible, i.e. that there are no such integers.

You make the claim that $2^x-1$ is prime. But you do not show how this follows from what you established so far. In fact the factorizations
$$15=3\times5,\qquad 63=3^2\times7,\qquad 255=3\times5\times17,$$
show that this claim is false.

A very quick and easy route to a proof is by considering remainders after division by $4$.